# Is it possible to apply converter implicitly in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project which contains bunch of images in its resources folder.
But now i want to use the images by downloading them in storage and then use it. But to do that i have to apply converter to all the images.
Is it possible to apply converter to all the images implicitly.Or any other method which is suitable here?

```
public class ImageFileToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is string name)) return null;
          return ImageSource.FromFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), name));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.

The thing that you can do is create your own inheritance of the control, always apply the converter in there and create a bindable property on it which feeds the regular property.

Answer (score 1):

I end up using like this

```
  public class StorageImage : Image
{
    public static string FolderName = "assest";

    public new object Source
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)base.Source;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Source = (ImageSource)ConvertFromInvariantString(value as string);
        }
    }

    public static object ConvertFromInvariantString(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;
            return ImageSource.FromFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), FolderName, value));
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually. Set the style in your App.xaml (or in code depends where have it, or other ResourceDictionary) set the style to all the images that want to use the converter as Source(I assume thats what u want to do).

Comment: Official documentation is superb: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/index